# wait for async call to finish before firing function in event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I am collaborating on a web project with someone who devised a series of .js scripts that act like 'plugins' in the sense that he would like them to be used on other web projects.

Most of these 'plugins' are event listener based, and they listen for clicks on elements with certain 'data' attributes. For example an element with 'data-setdata' will fire, on click, a listener in 'setdata.js':

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-setdata]', function(e) {
  // do something
});
```

But one of these plugins, 'ajax.js', fires a 'post' call for AJAX-style loading of content:

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-ajax]', function(e) {
    $.post(
      //etc
    );
  }
});
```

...**so of course we find ourselves in a situation in which we cannot control the order in which 'setdata.js' and 'ajax.js' occur**.

My initial thought was to get those plugins back into functions, and properly chain them using promises on a main .js

But, **is there a way to delay firing the function within an event listener until a certain async action has been fulfilled?** pseudocode:

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-setdata]', function(e) {
  when( ajax call finishes ){
    // do something
  }
});
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the "certain async action"?

Comment: @guest271314 it is the loading of some html content trough a post call, after a click on an element that has 'data-ajax' attribute. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22125915/5721273 I could use a setTimeout within the plugins, to continuously poll for changes on a flag set by the ajax call completion.

```
function checkFlag() {
    if(flag == false) {
       window.setTimeout(checkFlag, 100); /* this checks the flag every 100 milliseconds*/
    } else {
      /* do something*/
    }
}
checkFlag();
```

Of course this is not the proper way of doing it, which would be chaining promises.

But in the specific case-scenario that I described, in which there is a design limitation imposed by someone else, and when I already told this person about it, but still need to find a temporary workaround, this is the correct answer.

Comment: This is a bad way to accomplish what you want. You will be checking 10 times per second, which is wasteful, and will also not know immediately that the function has completed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `ajaxComplete` event

```
let done = false;

$(document).on("ajaxComplete", function(event, jqxhr, settings) {
  if (settings.url === "/path/to/resource" && !done) done = true;
});

$('body').on('click', '[data-setdata]', function(e) {
  if (done) {
    // do something
  } else {
    console.log(done)
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this would not wait for ajax then do action, but do action only if ajax finished, right ?

Comment: _"but this would not wait for ajax then do action, but do action only if ajax finished, right ?"_ What is the difference between the two scenarios that you are describing?

Comment: what I need is the action within the event listener to always execute, but only after the ajax call finishes;  I had the impression that in your example the event listener will check only once, when fired, if the ajax call has finished. If it has not, then it will go to 'else', instead of waiting for it to finish. Thanks

Comment: Then use `ajaxComplete` alone. Or use `.then()` to perform an action once the call has completed within the `click` handler. How is the `click` event related to the completion of an `$.ajax()` call?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax's `complete` option, which executes when the call is completed, no matter if it is successful or not.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",

    ....

    success: function(data) {
        // do some stuff
    },
    error: function(data) {
        // do other stuff stuff
    },
    complete: function(data) {
        // call your other function here 
    }
});
```